# Real-life examples of homogenous systems of linear ODEs with constant coefficients and complex eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I need some real-life examples of application of homogenous systems of linear ODEs with constant coefficients and complex eigenvalues. Most interesting examples I find are non-homogenous. This is for a linear algebra class I am teaching, so we only cover homogenous systems. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I may use the harmonic oscillation and second order ODE from here. But I was hoping for a linear system that does not arise from a single second order ODE.